# Opencv & PyGi : how to display an image read by opencv

Tags: python, opencv, pygtk

I want to display an image in PyGi, the image is read first by opencv. 
But,it fails.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf
import cv2
import numpy as np
window = Gtk.Window()
image = Gtk.Image()
image.show()
window.add(image)
window.show_all()
im = cv2.imread("file.bmp")
a = np.ndarray.tostring(img)
h, w, d = img.shape
p = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(a,GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, w, h, w*3, None, None)
image.set_from_pixbuf(p)
Gtk.main()
```

But the result is a black image.
Moreover, if I loop around a set of files (multiple .bmp files from a directory), I got coredump (suspecting GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data)

Is it the proper way to have opencv & PyGi interacting ?
I managed to use opencv with Tkinter, but I fail to use it with PyGi.

Comment: Do you need cv2 for anything else? Otherwise, it would be much simpler to just use `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(filename)`.

Comment: Yes, I need cv2 - the code above is just a reduction of the problem. The targeted application will get the images from a cam, not from file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using GdkPixbuf.PixbufLoader:

```
loader = GdkPixbuf.PixbufLoader()
loader.write(img)
loader.close()
pixbuf = loader.get_pixbuf()
image = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```

Comment: This does not work, here is the error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./simple.py", line 14, in <module>
    loader.write(im)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Item 0: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

(simple.py:13225): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: GdkPixbufLoader finalized without calling gdk_pixbuf_loader_close() - this is not allowed. You must explicitly end the data stream to the loader before dropping the last reference.

Comment: By the way, any link to documentation about PixbufLoader (python version) ?

Comment: The documentation of PixbufLoader is [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GdkPixbuf-2.0/classes/PixbufLoader.html#GdkPixbuf.PixbufLoader). I cannot really test your program (or my suggestion) as I do not have opencv for Python3 installed. You need to get the bytes of the `img`. Maybe, this can be done with `im.data[0:]` or a `tobytes` method.

Comment: thx for the link ... but not yet done : I have set the size prior the write. But still not ok. I wanted to specify then the image format (raw format I guess), but raw format is not available ( 'bmp', 'pcx', 'wmf', 'jpeg2000', 'xbm', 'gif', 'tiff', 'svg', 'qtif', 'ani', 'icns', 'ico', 'ras', 'wbmp', 'jpeg', 'pnm', 'xpm', 'png', 'tga').

Comment: I do not know how to display raw images directly. Maybe you can just convert them before showing them.

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked just fine for me. Perhaps the issue in your case was the two different variables '`im`' (in which you are reading the CV image) and '`img`' (the one that you are converting to string)?

Here is a simplified code that worked for me in displaying a video frame from camera:

```py
# OpenCV image:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, img = cap.read()
# Gtk Image:
img_gtk = Gtk.Image()
# Do other things such as attaching the 'img_gtk' to a window/grid...

# Convert and display:
h, w, d = img.shape
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data  (img.tostring(), GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, w, h, w*3, None, None)
img_gtk.set_from_pixbuf (pixbuf)
img_gtk.show()
```