# To many selection "changed" callbacks in PyGTK application

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm currently developing a PyGTK app consisting of three linked `Gtk.TreeView`'s. Selecting an element in text view `i` will trigger a reload of contents in text view `i+1`. But for some reason I get too many selection-changed-callbacks to text view `i+1` (one for each entry it seems) when text view `i+1` has a single selection and I change selection text view `i`.

Note that I'm calling, for instance, text_view.get_selection().unselect_all() and store.clear() for `i+1` and `i+2` when I change the selection text view `i`.

Does this have to do with the fact that I'm using multiple selections? Should I only unselect the currently selected ones?

Code follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# command line interface (CLI) parsing
import requests
import argparse
import datetime
import time
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

# graphical user interface (GUI)
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf, Colorspace # for images
from gi.repository import Gio
from io import BytesIO


# DICOM
from dicomweb_client.api import DICOMwebClient

# this directory


def try_get_attr(data, tag, default_value=None):
    '''Try get attribute indexed by TAG in DICOM data DATA.'''
    try:
        value = data[tag]['Value'][0]
        if data[tag]['vr'] == 'US':  # unsigned int
            return value             # return integer
        elif data[tag]['vr'] == 'DA':  # date
            return datetime.date(int(value[0 : 4]),
                                 int(value[4 : 6]),
                                 int(value[6 : 8]))
        elif data[tag]['vr'] == 'TM':  # time (of day)
            return datetime.time(int(value[0 : 2]),
                                 int(value[2 : 4]),
                                 int(value[4 : 6]))
        else:
            return value            # as is
    except:
        return default_value


def try_get_attr_alphabetic(data, tag, default_value=None):
    try:
        return try_get_attr(data, tag, default_value)['Alphabetic']
    except:
        return default_value


class StudyStore(Gtk.ListStore):
    '''Gtk.ListStore of DICOM studies (model).'''
    def __init__(self, client):
        Gtk.ListStore.__init__(self, str, str, str, str, str)  # TODO GDate, GTime
        self.client = client
        studies = self.client.search_for_studies()
        for study in studies:
            study_instance_uid = try_get_attr(study, '0020000D')  # TODO wrap in DicomUID when 'vr': 'UI'
            if study_instance_uid is None:
                continue        # skip because http://dev-demo.sectra.se contains lots of such entries
            study_name = try_get_attr(study, '00100020')  # TODO decode string when 'vr': 'LO'
            person_name = try_get_attr_alphabetic(study, '00100010')  # TODO decode Person Name string when 'vr': 'PN'
            study_date = str(try_get_attr(study, '00080020'))          # TODO GDate
            study_time = str(try_get_attr(study, '00080030'))          # TODO GTime
            # studies_id = try_get_attr(study, '00020010')  # TODO 'vr' : 'UI'. same for all elements in `studies`
            # study = client.retrieve_study(study_instance_uid)   # retrieve same thing again
            self.append((study_instance_uid, study_name, person_name, study_date, study_time))


class SeriesStore(Gtk.ListStore):
    '''Gtk.ListStore of DICOM serieses (model).'''
    def __init__(self, client):
        Gtk.ListStore.__init__(self, str, str)
        self.client = client

    def update_using_study(self, study_instance_uid):
        self.study_instance_uid = study_instance_uid
        self.serieses = self.client.search_for_series(study_instance_uid)
        for series in self.serieses:
            series_instance_uid = try_get_attr(series, '0020000E')  # Series Instance UID
            series_modality = try_get_attr(series, '00080060')  # Modality being either CR, OT, MR, XA, CT, US
            self.append((series_instance_uid, series_modality))


class InstanceStore(Gtk.ListStore):
    '''Gtk.ListStore of DICOM instances (model).'''
    def __init__(self, client):
        Gtk.ListStore.__init__(self, str, str)
        self.client = client

    def update_using_study_and_series(self, study_instance_uid, series_instance_uid):
        instances = self.client.search_for_instances(study_instance_uid,
                                                     series_instance_uid)
        for instance in instances:
            sop_class_uid = try_get_attr(instance, '00080016')  # SOP Class UID
            try:
                sop_name = SOP_UID_NAMES[sop_class_uid]  # lookup SOP name from UID
            except:
                sop_name = sop_class_uid  # if fails use UID
            sop_instance_uid = try_get_attr(instance, '00080018')  # SOP Instance UID
            self.append((sop_instance_uid, sop_name))


class DICOMWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self, title="DICOM Viewer"):
        self.client = DICOMwebClient(url="https://dicomcloud.azurewebsites.net",
                                     qido_url_prefix="qidors",
                                     wado_url_prefix="wadors",
                                     stow_url_prefix="stowrs")

        # construct top window
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self,
                            title=title,
                            vexpand=True, hexpand=True,
                            border_width=0)

        # create top grid
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid(vexpand=True, hexpand=True,
                             column_homogeneous=True,
                             row_homogeneous=True)
        self.add(self.grid)     # add it to parent window

        # STUDIES
        self.study_store = StudyStore(client=self.client)
        self.current_study_filter = None
        self.study_filter = self.study_store.filter_new()
        self.study_filter.set_visible_func(self.study_view_filter_func)
        self.study_view = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(self.study_filter)
        self.study_selection = self.study_view.get_selection()
        self.study_selection.set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)
        self.study_selection.connect("changed", self.on_study_view_selection_changed)
        for i, column_title in enumerate(["Study UID", "Study Name", "Person Name", "Study Date", "Study Time",]):
            if i == 0:
                continue        # skip "Study UID"
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
            self.study_view.append_column(column)
        self.study_view_scroller = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(vexpand=True,
                                                      hexpand=True)
        self.study_view_scroller.add(self.study_view)
        self.grid.attach(self.study_view_scroller,
                         left=0, top=0, width=1, height=1)

        # SERIESES
        self.series_store = SeriesStore(client=self.client)
        self.current_series_filter = None
        self.series_filter = self.series_store.filter_new()
        self.series_filter.set_visible_func(self.series_view_filter_func)
        self.series_view = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(self.series_filter)
        self.series_selection = self.series_view.get_selection()
        self.series_selection.set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)
        self.series_selection.connect("changed", self.on_series_view_selection_changed)
        for i, column_title in enumerate(["Series UID", "Series Modality"]):
            if i == 0:
                continue        # skip "Series UID"
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
            self.series_view.append_column(column)
        self.series_view_scroller = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(vexpand=True,
                                                       hexpand=True)
        self.series_view_scroller.add(self.series_view)
        self.grid.attach(self.series_view_scroller,
                         left=1, top=0, width=1, height=1)

        # INSTANCES
        self.instance_store = InstanceStore(client=self.client)
        self.current_instance_filter = None
        self.instance_filter = self.instance_store.filter_new()
        self.instance_filter.set_visible_func(self.instance_view_filter_func)
        self.instance_view = Gtk.TreeView.new_with_model(self.instance_filter)
        self.instance_selection = self.instance_view.get_selection()
        self.instance_selection.set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)
        self.instance_selection.connect("changed", self.on_instance_view_selection_changed)
        for i, column_title in enumerate(["SOP Instance UID", "SOP Class"]):
            if i == 0:
                continue        # skip "SOP Instance UID"
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
            self.instance_view.append_column(column)
        self.instance_view_scroller = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(vexpand=True,
                                                         hexpand=True)
        self.instance_view_scroller.add(self.instance_view)
        self.grid.attach(self.instance_view_scroller,
                         left=2, top=0, width=1, height=1)

        self.image_view = Gtk.Image()
        self.image_view_scroller = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(vexpand=True,
                                                      hexpand=True)
        self.image_view_scroller.add(self.image_view)
        self.grid.attach(self.image_view_scroller,
                         left=0, top=1, width=3, height=3)

        self.show_all()


    def on_study_view_selection_changed(self, selection):
        print('on_study_view_selection_changed: selection_count=', selection.count_selected_rows())

        # needs to be called in this order
        self.clear_current_image_and_pixel_data()
        self.clear_current_instance_store_and_view()
        self.clear_current_series_store_and_view()

        model, treeiter = selection.get_selected_rows()
        for row_index in treeiter:
            self.study_instance_uid = model[row_index][0]
            self.series_store.update_using_study(study_instance_uid=self.study_instance_uid)
            # TODO visually present:
            # study_metadata = self.client.retrieve_study_metadata(self.study_instance_uid)


    def on_series_view_selection_changed(self, selection):
        print('on_series_view_selection_changed: selection_count=', selection.count_selected_rows())

        # needs to be called in this order
        self.clear_current_image_and_pixel_data()
        self.clear_current_instance_store_and_view()

        model, treeiter = selection.get_selected_rows()
        for row_index in treeiter:
            self.series_instance_uid = model[row_index][0]
            self.instance_store.update_using_study_and_series(study_instance_uid=self.study_instance_uid,
                                                              series_instance_uid=self.series_instance_uid)
            # TODO visually present:
            # series_metadata = self.client.retrieve_series_metadata(self.study_instance_uid,
            #                                                        self.series_instance_uid)


    def on_instance_view_selection_changed(self, selection):
        print('on_instance_view_selection_changed: selection_count=', selection.count_selected_rows())

        # needs to be called in this order
        self.clear_current_image_and_pixel_data()

        model, treeiter = selection.get_selected_rows()
        for row_index in treeiter:
            self.sop_instance_uid = model[row_index][0]
            # TODO visually present more parts of:
            instance_metadata = self.client.retrieve_instance_metadata(study_instance_uid=self.study_instance_uid,
                                                                       series_instance_uid=self.series_instance_uid,
                                                                       sop_instance_uid=self.sop_instance_uid)[0]
            self.image_height = try_get_attr(instance_metadata, '00280010')  # rows
            self.image_width = try_get_attr(instance_metadata, '00280011')  # columns
            self.image_bits_per_pixel = try_get_attr(instance_metadata, '00280100')  # bits per pixel
            self.frame_count = try_get_attr(instance_metadata, '00280008', '1')  # only present for multi-frame image instances so default to 1
            transfer_syntax_uid = try_get_attr(instance_metadata, '00020010')
            if transfer_syntax_uid is not None:
                transfer_type = transfer_syntax_uid

            image_format = None  # possible values are None (uncompressed/raw), 'jpeg', or 'jp2'
            try:
                # start = time.time()
                frames = self.client.retrieve_instance_frames(study_instance_uid=self.study_instance_uid,
                                                              series_instance_uid=self.series_instance_uid,
                                                              sop_instance_uid=self.sop_instance_uid,
                                                              frame_numbers=[1],
                                                              image_format=image_format)
                # stop = time.time()
                # print("Took:", stop - start)
            except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                frames = []     # no frames
                pass

            # need to store frames because Pixbuf.new_from_data doesn't keep own
            # reference to data so Python will destroy it without Gtk knowing about it
            self.rgb_frames = len(frames)*[None]

            for image_index, frame in enumerate(frames):
                pixel_count = (self.image_width* self.image_height)
                rgb_frame_temp = bytearray(3*pixel_count)  # pre-allocate RGB pixels

                if image_format is None:  # raw pixels
                    if self.image_bits_per_pixel == 8:
                        for j in range(0, pixel_count):
                            gray8 = frame[j]
                            rgb_frame_temp[3*j + 0] = gray8
                            rgb_frame_temp[3*j + 1] = gray8
                            rgb_frame_temp[3*j + 2] = gray8
                    else:
                        raise Exception("Cannot handle bits_per_pixel being" +
                                        str(self.image_bits_per_pixel))

                    # Ref: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GdkPixbuf-2.0/classes/Pixbuf.html#GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data
                    # this better than `Pixbuf.new_from_bytes` which requires
                    # the data parameter to be wrapped in a GLib.Bytes object

                    # WARNING: be aware of that `new_from_data` is buggy. See for instance:
                    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501835/gtk3-gdk-pixbuf-new-from-data-gives-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-error-13
                    self.rgb_frames[image_index] = bytes(rgb_frame_temp)  # bytearray needs to be wrapped in a `bytes` and store here in order to enot loose ref
                    pixbuf = Pixbuf.new_from_data(self.rgb_frames[image_index],  # data
                                                  Colorspace.RGB, # colorspace
                                                  False,  # has_alpha
                                                  8,  # bits_per_sample
                                                  self.image_width,  # width
                                                  self.image_height,  # height
                                                  self.image_width*3,  # rowstride, 3 because RGB has 3 bytes per pixel
                                                  None, None)  # rely on Python for deallocation
                    if image_index == 0:
                        self.image_view.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
                elif image_format == 'jp2':
                    print("TODO Decode jp2 image...")
                    if False:
                        input_stream = Gio.MemoryInputStream.new_from_data(frame, None)
                        pixbuf = Pixbuf.new_from_stream(input_stream, None)
                        if image_index == 0:
                            self.image_view.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)


    def clear_current_series_store_and_view(self):
        self.series_store.clear()
        self.series_view.get_selection().unselect_all()


    def clear_current_instance_store_and_view(self):
        self.instance_store.clear()
        self.instance_view.get_selection().unselect_all()


    def clear_current_image_and_pixel_data(self):
        self.image_view.clear()  # remove image before
        self.rgb_frames = None   # drop pixel data


    def study_view_filter_func(self, model, iter, data):
        """Tests if the language in the row is the one in the filter"""
        if self.current_study_filter is None or self.current_study_filter == "Any":
            return True
        else:
            return model[iter][2] == self.current_study_filter


    def series_view_filter_func(self, model, iter, data):
        """Tests if the language in the row is the one in the filter"""
        if self.current_series_filter is None or self.current_series_filter == "Any":
            return True
        else:
            return model[iter][2] == self.current_series_filter

    def instance_view_filter_func(self, model, iter, data):
        """Tests if the language in the row is the one in the filter"""
        if self.current_instance_filter is None or self.current_instance_filter == "Any":
            return True
        else:
            return model[iter][2] == self.current_instance_filter


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = DICOMWindow()
    win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)  # make close button window work
    win.show_all()                         # show everything
    Gtk.main()                             # start event loop
```

Comment: I haven't fully grasped your question, but is your problem that your programmatic selection changes triggers changes that are difficult to separate from "real" ones? Can you block the event handlers when you know that you will trigger changes?

Comment: I would like to prevent change callsback from being triggered on a TextView when I (from another callback) unselect all its selected rows and clear its corresponding ListStore. Currently I get change callback for every entry in the TextVIew regardsless of whether its selected or not.

Comment: Will it solve your problem to block the signal handler at that time using [`handler_block`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.handler_block)?