# GTK segfault reading an ndarray

Tags: python, image, segmentation-fault, gtk, pygtk

I have several images from a live feed in a buffer and I want to display the images using GTK in Python. Basically, I was thinking of using a while loop that gets the latest frame in the buffer. But then I can't figure out how to show this in GTK.

The images are read using OpenCV, which creates an ndarray. Using

```
GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(image, GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, width, height, width*3)
```

I get a segfault. Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: I'd expect your code to raise [`TypeError: new_from_data () takes Exactly 9 arguments (7 given)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341988/converting-pil-gdkpixbuf) if you're using GTK3 - a little confused...  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501835/gtk3-gdk-pixbuf-new-from-data-gives-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-error-13) has same error, but no answer.  You might try [`new_from_bytes`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Image-Data-in-Memory.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-bytes).  Can you post `type(image)`, `image.shape`, `type(image[0][0])` ?

Comment: Thanks for the insights! The format of the image was incorrect. I got a 2D array, but expected an RGB-array. A different problem has surfaced though. The image displayed by the GUI is not what I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. By filling the PixBuf differently, I could get the image I expected. The solution was found at [Converting PIL Image to GTK Pixbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906814/converting-pil-image-to-gtk-pixbuf). It is the second answer.